# Is it possible to create in C# a predicate with a custom values, or templated values

Tags: c#, list, predicate

I am relatively new to C# and come from a C++ background.  I have been looking a list searches and the usages of `Find`.

I am trying to define a function that takes a parameter, and returns an entry from a list.  for example

```
class Product
{
    public string id;
    public string description;
}

public List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
// Add some items to the list
```

My question is, can I turn this following custom "Find" function using C# features like Predicates/Funcs

```
Product GetProductByID(string id)
{
    foreach (Product p in products)
    {
        if (p.id == id)
        {
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using Predicates, but I don't seem to be able to find anyway to feed a value in to the function to do the boolean expression check against.  I understand how I would write a Predicate to find a speciic item in a list, but not a dynamic one that could be passed in.

Ideally I would then like to go one step further and Template it so the Predicate could be used for any list of items that have a similar structure.

i.e if we also had

```
class Employee
{
    public string id;
    public int age;
}

public List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
// Add some items to the list
```

It would be really cool to use the same defined Predicate, but on this list of a totally different type. Ie something like

```
// psudo
Predicate<T, string> predicate = return <T>.id == id;
```

and it work because T is always of a type that has a string member called `id`

I Hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand how I would write a Predicate to find a speciic item in a list, but not a dynamic one that could be passed in.

This is where lambda expressions come in, allowing you to create an instance of a delegate type that capture variables in scope. For example:

```cs
public Predicate<Product> CreateProductPredicateForId(string id)
{
    return product => product.id == id;
}
```

Now in terms of making that *generic*, you'd need to have an interface that specifies an `Id` property. You can then write a generic method. For example:

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
    string Id { get; }
}
...

public Predicate<T> CreatePredicateForId<T>(string id) where T : IEntity
{
    return entity => entity.Id == id;
}
```

Comment: @MarcGravell: Whoops, yes - fixed.

Answer (score 3):

(note: throughout this I'm using `Func<T, bool>` - but the exact same logic applies to `Predicate<T>` - they have the equivalent signature, but you tend to see more of the former than the latter these days; that said: `List<T>` uses the latter)

Generics supports this, but via variance rules; you would have to declare an interface of the form:

```cs
interface IHazId
{
    int Id { get; }
}
class Foo : IHazId // your types need to implement it, too!
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can use it in a general way:

```
    void SomeCallingCode()
    {
        // get the predicate, however
        int id = 42;
        Func<IHazId, bool> predicate = obj => obj.Id == id;

        // use it
        SomeTypeSpecificMethod(predicate);
    }
    void SomeTypeSpecificMethod(Func<Foo, bool> predicate)
        => throw new NotImplementedException("not shown");
```

with the compiler/runtime allowing the `Func<IFoo, bool>` to satisfy a type-specific `Func<Foo, bool>` requirement, because it knows that all `Foo` are `IHazId`. You can also do this with generics with a constraint:

```
    void SomeCallingCode()
    {
        // get the predicate, however
        int id = 42;
        Func<IHazId, bool> predicate = obj => obj.Id == id;

        // use it
        SomeGenericMethod<Foo>(predicate);
    }
    void SomeGenericMethod<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        where T : IHazId
        => throw new NotImplementedException("not shown");
```

However, in reality, this is rarely useful, since in most cases you already know the types, and just want to do:

```
int id = 42;
SomeTypeSpecificMethod(x => x.Id == id);
```

Note also that the variance rules that allow you to treat `Func<IHazId, bool>` as `Func<SomeType, bool>` only work for *reference type* `SomeType` - which is to say: `class`, not `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Product GetProductByID(string id)
{
    foreach (Product p in products)
    {
        if (p.id == id)
        {
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

this could be replaced with

```
products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id)
```

The second part of you question could be easilly solved with inheritance, like

```
public class ProductA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProductB : ProductA
{
    
}

List<ProductA> a = new List<ProductA>();
List<ProductB> b = new List<ProductB>();

Func<ProductA, bool> findFunction = (p) => p.Id == id;

var p = a.FirstOrDefault(findFunction);
p = b.FirstOrDefault(findFunction);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use LINQ

```
Product myProduct = products.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

You need `using System.Linq;` on top of your file to use it.

Comment: Though this works for `Product` it does not solve OP's requirement to use a single predicate for different types having an `id`..